# 404 on including javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a node.js app that loads a signup form when visiting localhost/user/signup:

```
html
  head
    script(type='text/javascript',src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js')
    script(type='text/javascript',src='javascripts/validator.js')
    script(type='text/javascript',src='javascripts/signupValidation.js')
  body
    p(id='error', style='display:none;')#{error}
    form(id='signup',method='post',action='/signup')
      label(for='firstname') Firstname
      input(type='text', name='firstname')
      label(for='lastname') Lastname
      input(type='text', name='lastname')
      label Username
      input(type='text', name='username')
      label Password
      input(type='password', name='password')
      label Password again
      input(type='password', name='password2')
      label Email
      input(type='email', name='email')

      input(type='submit',value='Sign up', onclick="")
```

but when I access the page the server console logs a 404 error getting the JavaScript files, it was working fine until only resonantly when I changed the signup page to be loaded from `localhost/signup` to `localhost/user/signup`:

```
app.get('/signup',user.signupForm);
```

to:

```
app.get('/user/signup',user.signupForm);
```

Comment: You should describe exactly what configuration you changed, and what it looks like now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you question I assume, that you did not move the JavaScript files along, so your directory structure looks like this:

```
localhost
|- user
|-- signup
|- javascripts
```

In that case, the relative paths of you JavaScript files have to be changed in order to point towards the correct files:

```
script(type='text/javascript',src='../javascripts/validator.js')
script(type='text/javascript',src='../javascripts/signupValidation.js')
```

Remember that if you don't use absolute paths, paths are always treated as *relative to the current directory*, so in your case the system is searching for the JavaScript files in `localhost/user/javascripts/`, which does not exist and thus results in the 404 errors!